# Processing text with multiple delims in awk

Tags: bash, awk, text, unix-text-processing

I have a text which looks like -

```
Application.||dates:[2022-11-12]|models:[MODEL1]|count:1|ids:2320 
Application.||dates:[2022-11-12]|models:[MODEL1]|count:5|ids:2320
```

I want the number from the `count:1` columns so `1` and i wish to store these numbers in an array.

```sh
nums=($(echo -n "$grepResult" | awk -F ':' '{ print $4 }' | awk -F '|' '{ print $1 }'))
```

this seems very repetitive and not very efficient, any ideas how to simplify this ?

Comment: With GNU `awk`: `awk -F '[|:]' '{print $8}'`?

Comment: can you explain what `[|:]' does?

Comment: The answer is in the heading to your question. With regex `[|:]` `awk` uses `|` and `:` as input field separators.

Comment: @Cyrus, using a regexp in FS should be POSIX compliant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk once, set the field separator to `|`. Then loop all the fields and split on `:`

If the field starts with `count` then print the second part of the splitted value.

This way the `count:` part can occur anywhere in the string and can possibly print this multiple times.

```
nums=($(echo -n "$grepResult" |  awk -F'|' '
{
  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    split($i, a, ":")
    if (a[1] == "count") {
      print a[2]
    }
  }
}
'))

for i in "${nums[@]}"
do
   echo "$i"
done
```

Output

```
1
5
```

If you want to combine the both split values, you can use `[|:]` as a character class and print field number 8 for a precise match as mentioned in the comments.

Note that it does not check if it starts with `count:`

```
 nums=($(echo -n "$grepResult" |  awk -F '[|:]' '{print $8}'))
```

With `gnu awk` you can use a capture group to get a bit more precise match where on the left and right can be either the start/end of string or a pipe char. The 2nd group matches 1 or more digits:

```
nums=($(echo -n "$grepResult" | awk 'match($0, /(^|\|)count:([0-9]+)(\||$)/, a) {print a[2]}' ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try sed

```
nums=($(sed 's/.*count://;s/|.*//' <<< "$grepResult"))
```

Explanation:
There are two sed commands separated with ; symbol.
First command `'s/.*count://'` remove all characters till `'count:'` including it.
Second command `'s/|.*//'` remove all characters starting from `'|'` including it.
Command order is important here.

Comment: can you explain the regex magic?